# Create heating degree days (HDD) column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a heating degree days (HDD) column in a Pandas dataframe, using another column (df.temp) for the temperature.

Here's the formula I'd like to replicate in a Pandas dataframe:

```
df['hdd'] = max(0, (15 - df.temp))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np

df['hdd'] = np.maximum(0, (15 - df['temp']))
```

`numpy` vectorises calculations, so it applies across the series.

Comment: This works perfectly. I didn't realize it would be so easy. Thanks!